# Thread safe mutable configuration in Go

Tags: go

I'm surprised to see the lack of (in any) modules for a configuration module in Go which is thread safe for concurrent reads/writes.

I'm surprised there is no easy method to basically have something like https://github.com/spf13/viper, but thread safe.. where the Get/Set holds a Lock.

what's the right Go way to handle this without bloating code?

I normally use: https://github.com/spf13/viper however if the program for example as a GUI configuration is changeable during runtime, this package doesn't work.

I started doing the following

```
var config struct {
  lock sync.RWMutex
  myString string
  myInt int
}

func main() {
  config.lock.RLock()
  _ = config.myString // any read
  config.lock.RUnlock()
}
```

however this becomes very very tedious when accessing members to each time Lock/Unlock every single access for a read or a write and code becomes bloated and repetitive.

Comment: Normally you would use methods to access the fields with the locks.

Comment: The general solution is either use accessor methods or expose fields as [`atomic.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value)s or some other thread-safe interface.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use a configuration struct that is retrieved and updated atomically. This allows multiple fields to be updated in a single "transaction" and is easy to implement/use.

With Go1.18 and earlier this can be implemented with [`atomic.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value) and wrap with some simple helper functions to convert the type from `interface{}` to your `*config`.

It is even simpler with [`atomic.Pointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer) in Go 1.19:

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync/atomic"
)   

type config struct {
    str string
    num int
}   

var cfg atomic.Pointer[config]

func main() {
    // Store initial configuration.
    cfg.Store(&config{str: "foo", num: 42})
    
    // Clone and modify multiple fields.
    newCfg := *cfg.Load()
    newCfg.str = "bar"
    newCfg.num++
    cfg.Store(&newCfg)

    // Retrieve a value.
    _ = cfg.Load().str
}
```

With Go1.18 and earlier you can use [`atomic.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value) and wrap them with some simple helper functions to convert the type from `interface{}` to your `*config`.